# How to use variable in [ngStyle] in angular?

Tags: css, angular, ng-style

I want to change position depends on some events.
For example at the begining space from top should be 100px, but after button click should be 0px

```
<mat-list-item class="menu-item disabled " disableRipple (click)="toggleSubmenu($event)">
    <h3 matLine class="menu-item-text">Orchestration</h3>
  </mat-list-item>
```

I want to code some similar to

```
<mat-list-item class="menu-item disabled " disableRipple (click)="toggleSubmenu($event)" [ngStyle]={top: myVarilable+'px'}>
    <h3 matLine class="menu-item-text">Orchestration</h3>
  </mat-list-item>
```

but it doesnt work for me. Do you have some ideas to solve it?

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'margin-top': myVarilable+'px'}"` or `[style.margin-top]="myVariable+'px+"`

Comment: Adding styles into the template files can be really confusing to fix and work with later, @Smolarek. The "correct" way to do it would be creating two classes for each behavior you expect and, with the event, changing the class of the element.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used [ngStyle]='myStyle', and in .ts file I created myStyle variable :)

Comment: @smolarekman you can do this more easily. `[style.top.px]="myVarilable"` Please check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if is what you are looking for but you can pass an Object in the ngStyle, so you can use a function that returns a dynamically generated object.

Something like that.

**HTML**

```
<p [ngStyle]="setMyStyles()">
  You say tomato, I say tomato
</p>
```

**Component**

```
setMyStyles() {
  let styles = {
    'top': this.user.myVarilable + 'px',
  };
  return styles;
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use functions directly in templates for it causes memory leaks. Store the value in a variable and use it for binding or use a pure pipe instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this very simply.

```html
[ngStyle]="{'top.px': myVarilable}"
```

Otherwise:

```html
[style.top.px]="myVarilable"
```

Comment: The second one is very elegant and eminently useful.

Comment: Now I am curious how you could use the second "Otherwise" to assign multiple variables to multiple settings like background-color and color in the same statement?

Answer (score 6):

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': !clicked ? '0px' : '100px'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding below code on HTML and ts files.

HTML :

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyles()">
```

TS:

```
getStyles(): void {
    const myStyles = {
                'background': 'red,
            };
         return myStyles;
     }
```

Hope this will work fine.

Comment: That is an anti pattern. There are so many better alternatives mentioned in other answers, so if anyone stumbles on this issue - don't use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Angular v9 isn't a Option for my Project. So this works:

```
<div [style]="color">...</div>
```

```
color = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--someKey: ' + someVariable);
```

example 2:

```
[style]="colorTest(progressPercentageValueoutOfTotal, progressColor)"

colorTest(progressPercentageValueoutOfTotal, progressColor) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--percent: ' + progressPercentageValueoutOfTotal + '; stroke:' + progressColor);
}
```

I figured out, that it doesn't work if any other styles were set via [style.anyKey] or [ngStyle], so i had to create a container wich only contains the variable.